# NestJs/ClientProxy: Manual listen to events without decorators

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

Is there a manual way to subscribe to a event message pattern without using decorators on a function?
In a service, I send a message to a different microservice.
The call return nothing just void but asynchronously triggers an event, which i want to listen to in the service right afterwards

Example given, would maybe work like this

```js
// An event will be triggered later, after first value
await lastValueFrom(
  this.rabbitmqClient.send(RmqPatterns.DO_STUFF, payload),
);
    
// Now listening for that async event
this.rabbitmqClient.listen(RmqPatterns.DID_STUFF, async msg => {
  console.log(`Received message: ${msg.content.toString()}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the client like so:
(this code wasnt tested and may contain typos etc.)

```
@Injectable()
export class MqttCoreService implements OnModuleInit {
  protected mqttClient: MqttClient;

  constructor(
    @Inject('MQTT_SERVICE_CORE') protected mqttCoreClient: ClientMqtt,
  ) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    this.mqttClient = this.mqttCoreClient.createClient();

    // Get topics from some db and subscribe
    const topics = await this.someService.getTopics();
    topics.map(topic => {
      this.subscribe(topic);
    });

    this.mqttClient.on('message', handleMessage);
  }

  subscribe(topic: string) {
    return this.mqttClient.subscribe(topic);
  }

  async handleMessage(context: MqttContext, data: MqttCoreDtoModel | number) {...}
}
```